# Determining whether date in one table falls between dates in another table

Tags: reporting-services

I have two columns of dates, the first column is the date a purchase order was received to be inspected, the second is the date that purchase order was accepted or rejected. What I would like is a graph with dates on the X-axis, and then the number of purchase orders in the queue on that day on the Y-axis.

Some purchase orders are completed that day, so they would still be counted, but they might not get addressed for days or weeks, so they would be counted on all those days until they were addressed.

Sample data below:

```
Row ID     Date In      Date Out
1          9/1/18       9/1/18
2          9/1/18       9/1/18
3          9/1/18       9/2/18
4          9/1/18       9/3/18
1          9/2/18       9/2/18
2          9/2/18       9/4/18
```

So, it would be 4 for 9/1/18, 4 for 9/2/18, 2 for 9/3/18, and 1 for 9/4/18.

I asked a similar question for Excel, and had success with that.  However, we would like the data to be generated from within our ERP system (as opposed to copying the data to Excel manually), and I thought this might be possible using SQL and SSRS.

The formula for Excel was `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$1000,"<="&C1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$1000,">="&C1)`, so A and B were the Date In and Date Out columns, respectively, and then C was a column of all the days for the year.

I am not sure how I would a query like this, so I've started by making it similar to the Excel solution.  I generated a list of dates, and I am trying to compare a date in that list to my dataset of purchase order dates, but I'm not sure how to do that, since it's comparing one (row by row) to many.

Comment: Does each of those rows have some kind of ID (OrderID etc). If so can you show that too, t will be easier to solve then.

Comment: Yes, there is a Row ID that resets for each new date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a table of dates and then join it to your orders based on the date being **between** the Date In and Date Out so that they are counted in multiple days.

```
DECLARE @START_DATE AS DATE = '2018-09-01'
DECLARE @END_DATE AS DATE = '2018-09-30'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DATES')  IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DATES;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ORDERS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ORDERS;

SELECT 1 AS ROW_ID, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE) AS DATE_IN, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE) AS DATE_OUT
INTO #ORDERS
UNION
SELECT 2 AS ROW_ID, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE) AS DATE_IN, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE) AS DATE_OUT
UNION
SELECT 3 AS ROW_ID, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE) AS DATE_IN, CAST('2018-09-02' AS DATE) AS DATE_OUT
UNION
SELECT 4 AS ROW_ID, CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATE) AS DATE_IN, CAST('2018-09-03' AS DATE) AS DATE_OUT
UNION
SELECT 1 AS ROW_ID, CAST('2018-09-02' AS DATE) AS DATE_IN, CAST('2018-09-02' AS DATE) AS DATE_OUT
UNION
SELECT 2 AS ROW_ID, CAST('2018-09-02' AS DATE) AS DATE_IN, CAST('2018-09-04' AS DATE) AS DATE_OUT


;WITH GETDATES AS (SELECT @START_DATE AS DATE1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE1)
                  FROM GETDATES
                  WHERE DATE1 < @END_DATE
                 )
SELECT *
INTO #DATES
FROM GETDATES;

SELECT  DATE1, COUNT(O.ROW_ID) AS ORDERS
FROM #DATES D 
LEFT JOIN #ORDERS O ON D.DATE1 BETWEEN O.DATE_IN AND O.DATE_OUT
GROUP BY D.DATE1
```

Comment: I worked it into my existing query, but I am getting syntax errors at '#DatesFROM' and 'aWHERE'.  `INTO #Dates FROM (SELECT ones.n + 10 * tens.n + 100 * hundreds.n + 1000 * thousands.n as v FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n), 
(VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n), (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n)) a WHERE FORMAT(CAST('2018-09-01' AS DATETIME) + ( a.v / 10 ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) < CAST('2018-10-01' AS DATETIME)`

Comment: I updated my query to retrieve the table of dates with your method, and now I get a syntax error at 'GETDATES'.

Comment: I get a syntax error in Orders query at 'dbo': `SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY PartTran_TranDate) AS DateCount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PartTran_TranDate ORDER BY PartTran_TranDate ASC) AS [RowID],[PartTran_Company],[PartTran_TranType],[PartTran1_TranType],[PartTran_PartNum],[PartTran_TranDate],[PartTran1_TranDate],[PartTran_PONum],[PartTran_POLine],[PartTran_PORelNum],[PartTran_PackSlip],[PartTran_PackLine],[PartTran_TranQty],[PartTran2_TranType],[PartTran2_TranDate],[PartTran2_TranQty],[Calculated_Valid] INTO #ORDERS FROM dbo.[BAQReportResult_" + Parameters!TableGuid.Value + "]`

Comment: I've managed to get rid of the 'dbo' syntax error by wrapping that query in a WITH statement for GETORDERS, but now I get a syntax error at 'GETORDERS' and 'GETDATES'.

Comment: The table in your query above has `#ORDERS` as your table name. Maybe you used the wrong table names? What db source are you using? Oracle? You probably don't need to put your orders in a temp table - I only created it to put your data structure in it.

Comment: The DB source is Epicor ERP...not sure if they're using Oracle.

Comment: I removed the #ORDERS temp table, and it seems the 'dbo' syntax error has been resolved.  However, I am still getting a syntax error on 'GETDATES'.  Could it be an issue with `FROM GETDATES`?

Comment: Does the query run as is above for you? Some databases don't have the WITH (MySQL) or the syntax is different (Oracle). The SELECT INTO GETDATES would need to be right after the WITH statement.

Comment: If I run query as is, I get the following error: `Incorrect syntax near '#ORDERSUNIONSELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GETDATES'.
Incorrect syntax near '#DATES'.`

Comment: Hmm - it looks like it's not reading the return characters. Maybe add a space at the end of each line of the SELECT UNION to see if that makes it read it correctly.

Comment: Adding the spaces definitely helped...but now I'm getting an error about not being able to bind O.RowID.  This value is not part of my original table, it gets added in my SELECT statement...is there a way to take that first query (Orders) and then refer to the table that it creates at the end, instead of the base table (which lacks the RowID column)?

Comment: I wrapped my Orders table in a temporary table, and now it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing using "ReportItems!" property. Try to write expression something like:

```
iif(ReportItems!DateColumnX = somevalue, "Then Do something", "Else Do Something else")
```

Edits:

Try something like this:

```
Fields!ValueFromCurrentDataset(CompareLogic like(<,>,<> etc)) LookUp( Fields!ValueFromDataset2, "DataSet2")
```

Comment: The issue I'm having with this is that I'm comparing values between two datasets, so I am getting a scope error.

Comment: Isn't `Lookup` for 1-1 relationships?  This means it won't pick up the dates that are within the range of "in" and "out".